# CKEditor: Different color palettes for Text Color and Background Color possible?

Tags: colors, ckeditor, palette

I am using CKEditor (v3.6.4) and try to find out how to change the palettes for **Text Color** and **Background Color** separately.

I found `config.colorButton_colors` in the [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.colorButton_colors) which allows me to define the color palette. However, this palette is assigned to both, text and background.

How can I have two different palettes?

Answer (score 2):

The best and easy way is, Include required plugin at the download time or link below

[Ckeditor Builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder)

Answer (score 2):

Yes its actually possible. Just dont pick colors from the config but rather do the following in colorbutton/plugin.js:

```
        var textColors = '1ABC9C,2ECC71,3498DB,9B59B6,4E5F70,F1C40F,' +
                        '16A085,27AE60,2980B9,8E44AD,2C3E50,F39C12,' +
                        'E67E22,E74C3C,ECF0F1,95A5A6,DDD,FFF,' +
                        'D35400,C0392B,BDC3C7,7F8C8D,999,000';

        var backgroundColors = 'cee8fe,b1d7ff,c7d3f3,dfd6eb,e4cafe,ffbbff,ffbfd2,ff9999,ffdeb3,ffefb0,f4f98a,ffffbb,d3f1a1,bbffbb,bbffff,a6e3dc,c1ebc7,eddec9,f2ebd3,d3eaf2,e1eff3,ffbe61,ffdc61,e1f29d';


        var colors = (type == 'back') ? backgroundColors.split(',') : textColors.split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because the color palette is defined for the text color and background.

```
CKEDITOR.config.colorButton_colors =
'000,800000,8B4513,2F4F4F,008080,000080,4B0082,696969,' +
'B22222,A52A2A,DAA520,006400,40E0D0,0000CD,800080,808080,' +
'F00,FF8C00,FFD700,008000,0FF,00F,EE82EE,A9A9A9,' +
'FFA07A,FFA500,FFFF00,00FF00,AFEEEE,ADD8E6,DDA0DD,D3D3D3,' +
'FFF0F5,FAEBD7,FFFFE0,F0FFF0,F0FFFF,F0F8FF,E6E6FA,FFF';
```

Or you can change the **Text Color** plugin :)