# Change color palette of 'Text color' option in ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, css, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my project. I need to change the colour palette used for 'Text colour' and 'Background colour' options provided in the toolbar. Currently it shows,

[image]

But I want something like,

[image]

or

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to change this.

Thanks and Regards,

Neha

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361173/ckeditor-different-color-palettes-for-text-color-and-background-color-possible Duplicate

Comment: I tried using 'config.colorButton_colors' in config.js file, but it changes the colours which are listed in previous list of colours. I want to change the colour palette which appears after clicking on 'More colours'. Can you please help me and tell me what to do?